# asciidoc reuse table row across document

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I have a document with many similar tables. I thought it is possible to set this table cols and header as attribute

```
:table-params: width="100%",cols="12%,21%,67%",options="header"
:table-header: |this |is |header

.table
[{table-params}]
|====
{table-header}
```

but its get en error: `table missing leading separator`. Looks like asciidoc can't post-render attribute values. `pass` macro also didn't help

I found a solution with `include` macro with `tag`

```
.table-1
|====
// tag::table-header[]
|this |is |header
// end::table-header[]

.table-2
|====
include::example.adoc[tag=table-header]
```

Maybe I have missed something. What is a most elegant way to reuse marked-up parts across document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes effectively define string values that can be re-used throughout a document's content. However, a table's attribute definition requires a list of arguments, not a string that looks like a list of arguments.

The most elegant re-use for markup is the `include::` macro, which operates as if it injects the specified content at the location of the `include::` macro.

See the docs for more details: https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/directives/include/

Answer (score 1):

To avoid repetition, I would use the Jamal preprocessor.

https://github.com/verhas/jamal/

Jamal is a free, Apache v2.0 licensed tool that I wrote in the past few years to solve precisely the types of problems like yours.

With Jamal, you can define macros and use them in the code afterward, like:

```
{%@define tableParams= width="100%",cols="12%,21%,67%",options="header"%}
{%@define tableHeader=|this |is |header%}

.table
[{%tableParams%}]
|====
{%tableHeader%}
```

which will look in IntelliJ like the following:

[image]